# how to solve the error of localStorage is not defined?

Tags: javascript, next.js, local-storage

I am using the `next js` but when I want to use `localStorage` in my page it shows the error of `localStorage is not defined`  I read many articles but everyone advice to use `window.localStorage` but it also shows the error of `window is not defined` . I am very upset due to this problem. I use the `localStorage` in `serverSideProps`  the code is
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) 
    let user = {
        user:"",
        isAuth:""
    };
    const response = await fetch(
        `${server}/api/user/getUserData`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "mode": "cors",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'auth-token': localStorage.getItem('token')
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username })
    });
    const result = await response.json()
        .then(user => {

            if (user["user"][0] != null) {
                user.user = user["user"][0]
                user.isAuth = user.isAuth;
            }
            else {
                user.isAuth = 'false';
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    return {
      props: { user
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
  }
```

I am unable to find the solution can anyone can tell me the solution of this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

in next js getServerSideProps run only in server side not in you browser, thats why `window` or localstorage is undefined. You can't access localstorage in server its browser method.

see here for more https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16824